# Segmentation fault when try to copy float vector of large size through memcpy

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I am trying to copy a float vector into a void* variable through memcpy. If vector size is less than 3000, then below code works fine. But when try to copy vector of size greater than 3000, i got segmentation fault.

```
  void* process(std::string datatype) {
  //  given datatype will decide the dataype of vec.
  const uint64_t VEC_COUNT = 10; // vector size
  const uint64_t VEC_SZ = VEC_COUNT * sizeof(float);
  std::vector<float> float_vec;
  float_vec.reserve(VEC_COUNT);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < VEC_COUNT; ++i) {
    float val = (float)(rand() % 100) / 3.0f;
    float_vec.push_back(val);
  }

  void* data = nullptr;
  data = malloc(VEC_SZ);
  if (data == nullptr) {
    throw std::invalid_argument("Could not allocate memory for data!");
  }
  memcpy(data, &float_vec, VEC_SZ);
  }
 return data;
}

int main() {
 VEC_COUNT = 10; //will be same as in upper method
 void* data = process("float");
 std::vector<float> &k =
    *(static_cast<std::vector<float>*>(data));
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < VEC_COUNT; ++i) {
    std::cout << "k[i] = " << k[i] << " , float_vec[i] = "
      << k[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Before memcpy, I am using malloc to allocate memory. malloc is not giving any type of segmentation fault but memcpy not working fine.
When I run this code with gdb and backtrace segmentation fault, I got following error

```
__memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:249
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please, specify what you really want to achieve.

Comment: After `void* data = process("float")`, `data` points to an __unknown__ size of float values, you need at least a second parameter that will contain number of values `data` points to.

Comment: Yes I know I need that info. For now I am experimenting with different things that's why kind of hard-coded size in 'process' method and outside world.\

Comment: @Hasnain You cannot cast a dynamic array of `float` elements to a vector. That's not possible. Either use it as an array (`data[i]`), or create a new vector and copy the elements from the array into it. BTW, after edit, the code will not compile. `float_vec` does not exist in `main`.

Comment: @Hasnain Even after edit, it's not clear why do you need a plain dynamic array. Why do you not simply return the vector from `process` function?

Comment: The purpose of process method is to output any type of vector i.e int, float, double etc. And template is not a solution for me. I don't wanna get into that. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. But my goal is to make "process" a method which can return any type of vector. The receiver method/main will know the datatype of data returned from "process" method somehow wrapped in a void*. Then i want to make vector of given type from return of  "process" method. 
I hope now you will get more clear idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vector is just an "envelope" object holding a pointer to dynamically allocated memory that actually stores the elements. So if you take the address of the vector object itself, you are taking the address of the "envelope", but not that of the first element stored. So you are very likely reading beyound the bounds of the "envelop", and this is undefined behaviour; So it could be that it crashes with a size of 100, it could be that it does not crash with a size of 10000, but doing something else. At least it will not copy the actual elements as intended.

To get access to the memory where the vector actually stores the elements, use its member function `data()`. So the following command should do the job:

```
memcpy(data, float_vec.data(), VEC_SZ);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion and not having segmentation fault on memcpy. But now giving me error to convert data back to float vector.

Comment: @Hasnain why do you want to convert the data copied into `data` back into a vector???

Answer (score 3):

```
memcpy(data, &float_vec, VEC_SZ);
```

This cannot work, `memcpy` may be used only with *trivially-copyable* types, which `std::vector` is not.

What you likely want instead is:

```
memcpy(data, float_vec.data(), VEC_SZ);
```

Moreover, this:

```
std::vector<float> &k =
   *(static_cast<std::vector<float>*>(data));
```

is completely illegal. There is no object of type `std::vector<float>` on an address pointed to by `data`.

Comment: If  memcpy only work with trivially-copyable types, then why following line work fine when size of vector is in range 1-3000
```
memcpy(data, &float_vec, VEC_SZ);
```

Comment: @Hasnain It does not work fine. It works such that it can do _anything_, and your _fine_ is just one of these anything.

Comment: And i tried what you suggest, but when i try to convert void* to flaot vector using
"std::vector<float> &float_vec = *(static_cast<std::vector<float>*>(data));", i am getting segmentation error when try to access its value by index. @Daniel

Comment: @Hasnain I said that you cannot do that.

Comment: Then how to access data stored in memory. My problem is that, I want to copy float vector in some void* and return it from method. So other methods can use this.

Comment: Then simply `return data;` after (updated) `memcpy`. Why do you then define that reference-to-vector `k`? Why that `static_cast`?

Comment: if not casting to float vector or define reference to vector k, then how i can access value stored in data?

Comment: @Hasnain you cannot cast something to a vector. Period. [Edit] the question and show how you intend to call that function

Comment: @Jabberwocky I edited the question. Please have a look. Now question is more specified.

Comment: @Hasnain You can simply access stored elements by `data[i]` instead of `k[i]` in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors are not trivially copyable. Using `memcpy` on them has unspecified behaviour which may be undefined. Don't do this. Also, there is no need to use `malloc` in C++.

To copy a vector, this is an efficient solution:

```
std::vector<float> k = float_vec;
```

---

> I have method which can return vector of any type and i don't want to use templates.

Return `std::any`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But in my problem, i need to copy all data into a void*.

Comment: @Hasnain You cannot copy data into `void*`. `void*` can only point to data. `void*` can point at the data stored in the vector.

Comment: Make sense. But in my problem i need to copy data in void* variable and return from a method. If I simply assign a pointer to data to void*, when i go outside method scope, the data will be erased.

Comment: @Hasnain Return the vector instead.

Comment: I can't return a vector. Because I don't know the type of vector. In above mentioned its float, but sometime it can be int or double etc. And using template also not a good option for me. Return a void* is one of best solution for my problem.

Comment: @Hasnain How could the caller use the data if it doesn't know the type?

Comment: @Hasnain read this: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You have an XY problem here. You need to tell us what you're _actually_ trying to achieve.

Comment: @jabberwocky I have method which can return vector of any type and i don't want to use templates. In my case void* is one of best and clean solution. So method read vector type from config and after populating data into vector. I want that method to return data agnostic to datatype. The receiver of this data will get vector of desired type from void*.

Comment: @Hasnain please show how you intend to call this method. [Edit] the question and put all relevant information _there_

Comment: @eerorika i update the question. Please have a look